# jQuery drop-down navigation using unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a navigation dropdown with jQuery that looks like this:

```
<ul id="home" >
    <li class="navtab"><a href="#">TABANME</a></li>
    <li class="homesub"><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
    <li class="homesub"><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
    <li class="homesub"><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `<li>` `.navtab` is visible at all times - the sub-menu items start out hidden.  I've attached the `.hover()` to the `<ul>` element (`#home`), but when the cursor enters the sub-menu `<li>` elements, the `mouseout` for `#home` fires, and the sub-menu items hide.

I know this has to do with event bubbling and `mouseover`/`mouseout`, but I can't figure out the logic of how to keep the menu open while the cursor is over the entire `<ul>`.  The jQuery I currently have is:

```
$('#thome').hover(
    function(){
       tabShowSubnav($(this).attr('id'))
    },
    function(){
       tabHideSubnav($(this).attr('id'))
    });

function tabShowSubnav(menu){

var tb = '#' + menu;
var sb = '.' + menu.slice(1) + 'sub';

$(tb).css('height','239px');
$(sb).show();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do yourself a huge favour and change how you structure your menu markup to:

```
<ul id="home" >
  <li class="navtab">
    <a href="#">TABANME</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And put the hover event on li.navtab to make the submenu visible. You'll find this **much** easier to do. For example, the CSS:

```
ul.submenu { display: none; }
```

with:

```
$(function() {
  $("li.navtab").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("ul.submenu").show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).children("ul.submenu").hide();
  });
});
```

and you're most of the way there.

That all being said, I'd ***highly*** suggest using an existing jQuery menu plugin. There are lots of these about. I've had relatively good experience with [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/). There's little point reinventing this particular wheel.

Comment: +1 for Superfish. It's a great way to build these kinds of menus really easily.